# Loading Sounds With LWJGL and Slick-Util

Tags: java, audio, nullpointerexception, lwjgl

I'm creating a basic game, and I can load images fine. Now, I'm trying to load sounds but I keep getting **NullPointerExceptions**. I'm 100% sure the path is correct, I've tried loading more then one sounds and I always get this error. I've only been able to use it once.

Here is my sound bank:

```
public class SoundBank {

    public static Audio oggEffect;

    public SoundBank () {
        try {
            oggEffect = AudioLoader.getAudio("OGG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("Res/ping_pong_8bit_plop.ogg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

And my execution code:

```
else if (Keyboard.isKeyDown(Keyboard.KEY_8)) {
    SoundBank.oggEffect.playAsSoundEffect(1.0f, 1.0f, true);
}
```

Comment: Did you initialize the oggEffect object by saying "new SoundBank()" anywhere before calling it?

Comment: When I do that I get a Exception in thread "main"  java.lang.RuntimeException

Comment: This has to do something with the library. Sorry, I can't help you there, but I'm sure that there are some people with the same problem who already posted a thread in the forums of the libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it should be

```
/res/ping_pong...ogg
```

not

```
res/ping_pong...ogg
```

Answer (score 0):

never initialize a static variable through constructor.

Method 1 (this prevent you from having to call `new SoundBank();` to init):

```
public class SoundBank {

    public static Audio oggEffect;

    static {
        try {
            oggEffect = AudioLoader.getAudio("OGG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("Res/ping_pong_8bit_plop.ogg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Method 2 (I have it working like this):

```
public class SoundUtils {
    public static void playSound(String res) {
        try {
            Audio a = AudioLoader.getAudio("OGG", ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream("res/sfx/" + res + ".ogg"));
            a.playAsSoundEffect(1, 1, false);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //You don't need this.
            LoggerSys.get().getCurrentLogger().log("wtf i haz dun err0rz (" + e.toString() + ")");
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Oh, and make sure the path is correct (`Res/...` instead of `res/...` etc.)